# Hide text if not homepage

Tags: customization, pagination, homepage

I want to add text but only appear on the homepage only. I have used this if script:

```
<?php if( is_home() ) : ?>
<p>Some text</p>
<?php endif;?>
```

but the problem with this is it's appearing on every paginated page. So for example if I view `http://www.example.com/page/2/` it will show that text. I only want it appear on 1st page.

Any fix to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`is_paged()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_paged)

> ...checks if page being displayed is "paged" and the current page number is greater than one. This is a boolean function, meaning it returns either TRUE or FALSE.

You can adjust your code as follows

```
<?php if( is_home() && !is_paged() ) : ?>
    <p>Some text</p>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Note that `is_home()` checks if we're on the blog page; `is_front_page()` will return true when on the homepage.

Comment: `is_home()` returns true on homepage and blogpage. `is_front_page()` returns true on homepage and front page, but the front page is **not** the homepage

Answer (score 0):

There is another way you can show text block in all pages and categories but hide it on the homepage and vice versa.

```
<?php if( is_front_page() =="" ) : ?>
     <p>Some text here</p>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Why do you compare a boolean value (`is_front_page()`) with a _string?_ Just drop the comparison.

Comment: I made the comparison to "show the text" in all pages but homepage. If i removed the comparison the text will "appear in homepage" and disappear in other pages.

Comment: The canonical way is `if ( ! is_front_page() )`. :) Comparing boolean values with strings just makes you code less readable.

Comment: Wow! you're correct, i forgot this rule. Thanks for sharing :)